# Sales Table for analysis purposes

Tags: mysql

Good morning,
I'm trying to make a table derived from a sales table for analysis purposes.
I have data in these columns:

```
date | product_id | product_price | category
```

I want the output to be:

```
month | category1_quantity | category1_sales | category1_%_of_month_sales | category2_quantity.....category4_%_of_month_sales
```

I'm new to `mysql` can you help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, assuming your original table is called `sales`:

```
select monthly_category_sales.month
, monthly_category_sales.category
, monthly_category_sales.quantity
, monthly_category_sales.sales
, monthly_category_sales.sales*100/monthly_sales.month_sales as month_sales_pct
from
    (select month, category, count(product_id) as quantity, sum(product_price) as sales 
    from
        (select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as month, sales.* 
        from sales)sales_1
        group by month, category) monthly_category_sales
join
    (select month, sum(product_price) as month_sales 
    from
        (select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as month, sales.* 
        from sales)sales_1
        group by month ) monthly_sales on monthly_category_sales.month = monthly_sales.month
```

I added a calculated column `month` to your original dataset and then grouped by that.
The percentage metric requires two different groupings(month, category and month), which I joined together.

In order to pivot the output of that query into the format you specified, you'd have to do something cumbersome like this:

```
select month
,sum(category1_quantity) as category1_quantity
,sum(category1_sales) as category1_sales
,sum(category1_month_sales_pct) as category1_month_sales_pct
,sum(category2_quantity) as category2_quantity
,sum(category2_sales) as category2_sales
,sum(category2_month_sales_pct) as category2_month_sales_pct
    -- and so on for each category
from    
(select month
    ,case when category = 'category1' then quantity else 0 end as category1_quantity
    ,case when category = 'category1' then sales else 0 end  as category1_sales
    ,case when category = 'category1' then month_sales_pct else 0 end  as category1_month_sales_pct
    ,case when category = 'category2' then quantity else 0 end  as category2_quantity
    ,case when category = 'category3' then sales else 0 end  as category2_sales
    ,case when category = 'category4' then month_sales_pct else 0 end as category2_month_sales_pct
    -- and so on for each category
from (<insert the previous query here>) unpivoted_summary)pivoted
group by month
```

Comment: Hi @sonam_zangmo, thanks for your help! The first part runs smoothly while i'm having troubles with the second one. It returns 0 for every column.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your sales data?
Do your actual category values match the stings in the inner sub-query? e.g. 'category1'

Comment: From your proposed edit Pietro, I see that you got it working by inserting your actual category values ('Wrap', 'Meal', 'Beverage', 'Snack')
However, I'll keep my answer generic and consistent with your original question.